# Как понять, какую колизию коснулся объект?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, unity3d-android

Всем привет. Перейду сразу к делу. У меня есть объект на котором висит 2 коллайдера. Как мне в коде понять, какого конкретно коллайдера коснулся игрок?

Comment: `Collision.collider` ?

Comment: Возможно я зря не указал, но у меня оба коллайдера являются триггерами

Comment: Вы используете OnTriggerEnter или что то такое?

Comment: Да, и просто в other нету other.collider

Comment: Потому ваш `other` и есть объект типа `Collider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выяснили в комментариях, что автор использует оба коллайдера, как триггеры.

В Unity как правило такие методы возвращают объект непосредственно типа `Collider`, которого коснулся игрок.

Comment: А, всё, понял, большое спасибо!